# CSS Border Radius IE Background

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border

When using border-radius in IE (11) we are noticing the background is showing from the div behind, Does anyone have any ideas to stop the background showing through and to keep it a solid red?

The css for the table column is:

```
table.data th.first {
background-color: #990000;
padding-top: 1px;
border-top-left-radius: 8px;
height: 25px;
margin: 15px 0 0;
color: #fff;
background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding;
-webkit-background-clip: padding;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try collapsing the border?

Comment: a view more details would be nice. is it a child element?
what about z-index?
or set the border/outline of the child also the same color.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding`border: 1px solid #900;`

http://jsfiddle.net/sinnix/93y57tfr/3/